# How can I integrate Google sign-in in to my app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I know you been asked this question before but hopefully my question is a little more than just being able to sign in.

Ok so I've already got firebase added to my app and my users sign in using the email and password method in my login class. all works fine. But I also want to integrate google sign in.

I've placed all the code and tried my app and it does try to sign me in.. but this is my problem.

when it goes to login to my main activity it crashes because in my main activity I use

```
 Firebaseuser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
 String userid = user.getUid
```

I can't figure out how to create a Uid for a google user and to tell my app to use that if signed in with google else use the above line of code..

any help would be very much appreciated thanks for you time guys

Comment: User Id is created by firebase automatically when user logs in ...

Comment: thanks just realised that once the code has been added from the dev page i have to go back n add the firebase code. this then grabs the user id.. haha im such an idiot. fingers crossed this will sort my problem